# Angular Directive scope undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using a directive to parse a xls file and pass the data to a button via scope. The problem is that within the link function I'm binding to the element change event and calling a function that parses the xls file, but scope is undefined within the handleFile function, so I can't pass the data on to the button. What's the correct way to get the data to the button?

```
angular.module('fileReaderModule')
.directive('xlsReader', function(){

return {
    scope: {
        search: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, e, attr) {
        e.bind('change', handleFile);
    },
    template: '<input type="file" ng-model="xlsFile"><button ng-click="search({stuff: scope.stuff})">Search</button>'
}

function handleFile(scope, e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var i,f;
    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = f.name;
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;

            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
            scope.stuff = workbook.Strings; // scope not available here
            /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
            var result = {};
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                if(roa.length > 0){
                    result[sheetName] = roa;
                }
            });
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    } 
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the templates you don't need to use `scope`.

Replace this:

```
template: '<input type="file" ng-model="xlsFile"><button ng-click="search({stuff: scope.stuff})">Search</button>'
```

with this:

```
template: '<input type="file" ng-model="xlsFile"><button ng-click="search({stuff: stuff})">Search</button>'
```

You should also declare your function like this:

```
angular.module('fileReaderModule')
.directive('xlsReader', function($timeout){

    return {
        scope: {
            search: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, e, attr) {
            e.bind('change', scope.handleFile);

            scope.handleFile(e) {
              var files = e.target.files;
              var i,f;
              for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var name = f.name;
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    //Async code, need $timeout call so angular runs a digest cycle and updates the bindings
                    $timeout(function(){
                        var data = e.target.result;

                        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
                        scope.stuff = workbook.Strings;
                        var result = {};
                        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                            var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                            if(roa.length > 0){
                                result[sheetName] = roa;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
            }
        }
    },
    template: '<input type="file" ng-model="xlsFile"><button ng-click="search({stuff: stuff})">Search</button>'
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Not really cleaer on when to use $timeout, though.

Comment: $timeout should be used to wrap the async code so angular runs a digest when the reader.onload event is triggered... This forces angular to update all it's bindings. My last edit shows how it's done.

Comment: $scope.$apply() is also an alternative... you could run it as the last line inside the reader.onload function, but it might trigger an error if an angular digest is already running.. $timeout waits for a possible angular digest running before running another, therefore preventing any errors.